# I need assistance for api-here geocoding

Tags: geocoding, here-api

I would like to know how to obtain all London postal codes that start with "W2", for example, something like [this](http://www.geonames.org/postalcode-search.html?q=London+City+W2&country=). We are using the **geocode api** but in the postalCode parameter it asks for the exact postal code. We have also tried to use the **autocomplete api** but I also do not get a list of all the postal codes, it does a search in different parameters and it is not what we need.

This need arises because we are changing from MapServer to Nokia Here and with MapServer the api geocoding if it returns a list of all the postal codes

We are using something like this https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=xxxxxx&app_code=xxxxxxx&query=W2&country=GBR

We would need to be able to indicate in the query a complete or partial postal code

[this example verifies what we need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azL08.png)

By the way, we are using a payment license, how can I request this assistance?

Comment: Your first link doesn’t work (just takes us to the page of the URL shortening service itself), and what you actually want to know is also rather unclear. I suppose this API has a documentation? So start checking that for whether what you want is possible or not.

Comment: the link "autocomplete ...." does not work because it does not have the app_code, this is for nokia support

Comment: ok I have edited the link

Comment: So, again, what does the documentation of that API you are using there say about this?

Comment: thank you, read your my question and look at the image in the link "this example verifies what we need"

Comment: So, again, what does the documentation of that API you are using there say about this? (I can keep doing this all day if you want, question is will _you_ at some point start to make an actual effort …)

Comment: go again you, I do not see that you have answered any question about Nokia Here, do you work there? I think you contribute more if you do not try to respond, so you compensate for my lack of real effort. I'll wait if you want to answer Nokia, thanks again.

Comment: This is not a Nokia support channel, if you want support from Nokia, you better contact them.

Comment: Well it seems that if it is, https://developer.here.com/contact-us

Comment: Well just because they say it is, doesn’t automatically make it so. But you can of course wait and hope that one of their people stumbles upon this, based on the tags …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can constraint search result upto maximum 20 using geocoding autocomplete API with the below parameter

```
maxresults = { Valid range: 1 to 20 }
```

This constraint is as per API design. For detail information kindly go through the below link.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/topics/resource-suggest.html